# Numerics for continuity equation with Sobolev vector field

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Has any work been done about *numerical methods* for the continuity equation 
$$
\partial_t \rho(x,t) + \operatorname{div} (b(x,t) \rho(x,t)) = 0, \qquad t \in [0,T], \quad x \in \mathbb R^N, 
$$
where $b \in L^1_tW^{1,p}_x$?

---

A related equation has been asked on [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195547/numerical-methods-to-solve-a-continuity-equation).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I wrote a short-hand for $L^1((0,T), W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N))$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a function $b(x,t)$ for which standard numerical methods don't work?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I don't know what works (that's implicit in the question), but my understanding is that you need to assume $b$ smooth to get convergence estimates for numerical methods for the continuity equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the standard numerical methods (at least some of them) work even in the Sobolev regularity setting, the analysis of convergence is far from being trivial (due to non-smoothness of $b$). It is addressed for instance in the papers

1. A. Schlichting, C. Seis: *[Convergence rates for upwind schemes with rough coefficients](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.09156)* SIAM J. Numer. Anal., 55(2), 2017.
2. A. Schlichting, C. Seis: *[Analysis of the implicit upwind finite volume scheme with rough coefficients](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02534)*, Numer. Math. 139(1), 2018.